# Some users' badges are not displayed below their avatar in their profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

I noticed a lack of badges when browsing [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant?tab=profile)'s profile page. I know this user has earned several dozen badges.

[image: No badges under avatar]

I thought this might be a new user setting, but turns out, it's not. Unless it's only rolled out to some users. Then I thought maybe it's a new design choice where you can only see your own badges, but I looked on a different user's profile and could see his badges just fine.

Update:
This is probably related to this: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/832590514063015936

> Deploying a large change to badges backend storage to Stack Overflow, site may be slow for a few minutes.
>    - Nick Craver

(Thanks Bhargav for pointing that out). I don't see any mention of badges possibly *missing* though.

Comment: I poked Nick and he is looking.

Comment: That person hasn't earned any badges, what are you talking about?

Comment: @TinyGiant Quite impressive, considering their reputation!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update: Stack Overflow was manually fixed. All sites will re-sync tonight as part of their normal process.

This was a query bug, a fix is rolling out now and I'll re-sync all offended. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Do we need to notify you if we are "offended"? :)